# Do the Infinity Stones exist in Shang-Chi's timeline?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones, shang-chi-legend-of-the-ten-rings

In *Shang-Chi and The Legend of The Ten Rings* (2021), Soo speaks to Shang and Katy:

> Soo: Look, we're now living in a world where at any moment **half the population can just disappear**. Life's too short and too fragile.

Do the Infinity Stones exist in Shang-Chi's timeline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're asking whether *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* takes place in the main MCU timeline -- the same timeline in which *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Avengers: Endgame* were set -- the answer is yes.

The film's director, Destin Daniel Cretton, confirmed in [an interview with Fandango](https://www.fandango.com/movie-news/shang-chi-director-destin-daniel-cretton-reveals-new-details-about-marvels-next-big-historic-action-movie-754385) that the film is set in the main MCU, and takes place after the [Blip](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Blip), which is what Soo was referring to in the dialogue you quoted.

> Fandango: This is the second film in the MCU’s Phase Four. The first, *Black Widow*, was a prequel set between *Captain America: Civil War* and *Avengers: Infinity War*. With regards to the MCU timeline, when is *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* set?
>
> Destin Daniel Cretton: *Shang-Chi* is set in the present day in the MCU timeline.
>
> Fandango: Okay. So, like post-Blip, present day, is where we’re at?
>
> Destin Daniel Cretton: Yeah, yeah.
>
> <sub>‘SHANG CHI’ DIRECTOR DESTIN DANIEL CRETTON REVEALS NEW DETAILS ABOUT MARVEL’S NEXT BIG HISTORIC ACTION MOVIE</sub>

If you're asking whether the Infinity Stones still exist at the point in the timeline in which *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* is set, the answer is no, as Thanos used the Stones to destroy the Stones off-screen, between *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Avengers: Endgame*. The Stones still exist at earlier points in the timeline, though, as shown in *Avengers: Endgame*.

> NATASHA ROMANONFF: Where are the Stones?
>
> THANOS: Gone. Reduced to atoms.
>
> BRUCE BANNER: You used them two days ago!
>
> THANOS: I used the stones to destroy the stones.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame* (2019)</sub>

I don't know if you watched the mid-credits scene in *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* or not, but in case you didn't, Bruce Banner and Captain Marvel made a brief appearance, and Bruce's arm was shown to be in a sling as a result of the burns the Hulk sustained when he used the Infinity Gauntlet in *Avengers: Endgame*.

> <sub>*Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* (2021)</sub>

Again, I'm not sure if you were aware of this or not, but in case you weren't, Trevor Slattery is the same character who previously appeared in *Iron Man 3*.

> <sub>*Iron Man 3* (2013)</sub>